# Windows 10 and Computer vs Hostname

Tags: windows, git-bash

I am on Windows 10 and using GitBash.  I have "\h" in my PS1 prompt, but isn't showing my actual hostname.  Its showing my computer name.

Here is my "About" information:

Device name DawsonsLaptop
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)
Device ID   475A1176-4692-433D-B57E-176752212E0B
Product ID  00325-81882-70015-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

What do I need too put in my PS1 prompt?

Thanks
Dawson

Here is my PS1 prompt: PS1="${GREEN}ganymede@${BLUE}dawson:${ICYAN}\W${RESET}${IYELLOW} $(parse_git_branch) $ "

As shown above from Windows About my Computer Name is DawsonsLaptop and the hostname is ganymede. If I put \h in my PS1 prompt I get DawsonsLaptop not ganyemede which is my hostname. I just mentioned GitBash as that is the shell I am using not PowerShell not that difference means much to my issue/question.

Thanks Dawson

Comment: Please post your current PowerShell script that sets your prompt.

Comment: Also, why are you mentioning `git` `bash` when you're asking about PowerShell? They're completely different shells...

Answer (score 0):

[The PowerShell 7.1 documentation for customizing the prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1) covers your exact scenario, in-fact:

> #### [How to customize the prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1#how-to-customize-the-prompt)
>
> [...]
>
> For example, the following prompt includes your computer name:
>
> ```
> function prompt {"PS [$env:COMPUTERNAME]> "}
> ```

I tried it just now and it works for me:

[image]